# Join columns that do not satisfy the condition

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df:

```
df1:
            A    B     C
test1     1.06  4.0  6.00
test2     1.02  4.1  6.20
test3     1.07  0.9  6.10
test4     4.00  1.1  6.05
```

then I divide each row by the previous obtaining this:

```
df2:
             A         B         C
test1       NaN       NaN       NaN
test2  0.962264  1.025000  1.033333
test3  1.049020  0.219512  0.983871
test4  3.738318  1.222222  0.991803
```

I am looking that for each value higher than 1.35 (in `df2`) or less than 0.65 multiply the previous rows of `df1` by that value higher than 1.35 or less than 0.65.

The desired output would look something like this:

```
             A         B         C
test1      3.96       0.87     6.00
test2      3.81       0.90     6.20
test3      4.00       0.90     6.10
test4      4.00       1.10     6.05
```

The code I've made is this:

```
df_filtrado=pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(df2)):
    for j in range(len(list(df2.columns))):
        if df2.iloc[i,j]>1.35:
            values_higher=pd.concat([df1.iloc[0:i+1,[j]]*df2.iloc[i,j],df1.iloc[i+1:,[j]]])
            if df_filtrado.empty:
                df_filtrado= values_higher
            else:
                df_filtrado=pd.concat([df_filtrado,values_higher],axis=1, join_axes=[df_filtrado.index])
        elif df2.iloc[i,j]<0.65:
            values_lower=pd.concat([df1.iloc[0:i+1,[j]]*df2.iloc[i,j],df1.iloc[i+1:,[j]]])
            if df_filtrado.empty:
                df_filtrado= values_lower
            else:
                df_filtrado=pd.concat([df_filtrado,values_lower],axis=1, join_axes=[df_filtrado.index])

print df_filtrado
```

The current output up to here does okay and returns the following:

```
          B         A
test1  0.878049  3.962617
test2  0.900000  3.813084
test3  0.900000  4.000000
test4  1.100000  4.000000
```

What I am not capable of doing is to add the column that does not has any values higher than 1.35 or lower than 0.65 , like column C of `df2` .

This is what I have tried (adding it to the previous code):

```
    normal=pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:,i])
    if df2.iloc[:,i].all()>0.65 and df2.iloc[:,i].all()<1.35:

        if df_filtrado.empty:
            df_filtrado= normal
        else:
            df_filtrado=pd.concat([df_filtrado,normal],axis=1, join_axes=[df_filtrado.index])


print df_filtrado
```

However the output returned is :

```
         A         B    B         A     C
test1  1.06  0.878049  4.0  3.962617  6.00
test2  1.02  0.900000  4.1  3.813084  6.20
test3  1.07  0.900000  0.9  4.000000  6.10
test4  4.00  1.100000  1.1  4.000000  6.05
```

How can I return the desired output??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think simpliest is use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) if no `NaN` values:

```
df = df_filtrado.combine_first(df1)
```

If possible some `NaN`s:

```
mask = ((df2 < 0.65) | (df2 > 1.35)).any()
df = df1.loc[:, ~mask]
print (df)
          C
test1  6.00
test2  6.20
test3  6.10
test4  6.05

df = pd.concat([df_filtrado, df], axis=1)
print (df)
              B          A     C
test1  0.878049   3.962617  6.00
test2  0.900000   3.813084  6.20
test3  0.197561   4.000000  6.10
test4  1.100000  14.953271  6.05
```